# upload file directory main root

Tags: php

Can I set the folder root to always start from the top site folder?

```
$usersFiles = 'images/usersFiles/';

if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $usersFiles.$files['file']['name'][$i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the above would work, provided your `$files` array is correctly formatted.

Your example is actually very similar to php.net's own example of `move_uploaded_file` function definition: [PHP: move_uploaded_file - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can :

- http://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php
- [How to set root folder for PHP include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882915/how-to-set-root-folder-for-php-include-files)