# Owner Read Write Only Files Showing Error on Include Files in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP file in which I'm including some other files in same folder.  They are database connection and query files.  When I'm giving those included files only owner read and write only access then when I'm running the main file where they are included, its throwing SQL exception there.  When I'm giving permission for readable for others then it works.  Is it true that if files are owner read and write only then it wont work in the main file on running browser?  Or is there any way of keeping access only to owner for included files?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly: PHP (or rather your webserver) runs as its own user.  It may not be able to read the files if they are owned by someone else.  You may want to change the group ownership/permissions of the files.

Comment: so if its owners read and write only files.then they will not b read is it when we run those?

Comment: Who owns the files?  They may be owned by a different user than the one Apache/PHP is running as.  (I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding the question correctly.)

Comment: files are owned by root user

Answer (score 0):

you said that your app is throwing an SQL exception. That implies that the error is coming when your php code attempts to access your database manager rather than a php include error. If the php files were not being included, you should get an HTTP500 error when php encounters a variable or function in those included files that it cannot access. Because you're getting an SQL error, I would check to see what user id is being used to access your database and if that userid has the correct permissions in the database to access the tables needed by the SQL statements.

Comment: app is showing error only when connection file is having owner permissions.but when its assigned fr other users permissions as well.then app works fine.so there is no variable problem involved i guess

Comment: connection failure first of all.as basic include file in connection first

Comment: easy way to check if the files are being include is to check if one of the functions in that file is present. What do you get if you execute the following: if (function_exists('your function name')){echo "include works";}else{echo "include fails";}

Comment: its failing.wht shud i try nw

Comment: you can either give the web server user id RW access to your files/directory or the group in which the web server is running. I'd go for user id, first. You can find the current user running the script via the php "get_current_user()" command.

Comment: its the same users ownership i had given to files

Comment: php has a specific set of places it looks for includes. I would expect you to be getting an include failure, or a require_once failure when you attempt the include. php will tell you where it looked for the files. You can also run the following as a php command on your server and then search for include. It will tell you where php expects to find included files. 
    <?php 
        phpinfo();
    ?>

Comment: which thing need to check in phpinfo.php for include

Comment: search for include, you're looking specifically for "include_path" which will show something like "usr/local/PEAR:/php/includes". The PEAR directory is typically hidden from all access to your web server so is generally much harder to hack.

Comment: got this line.hw can it help me in correcting my problem sir

Comment: whatever it shows, that's where php is expecting the include or require_once files to be located. Are the files you are including on that specific path? If not, put them there and reload your app.

Comment: for me include path in info is like this-.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

Comment: that means that php is going to look in the usr/share/pear directory and in the usr/share/php directory for the files which it includes via the include statement or the require_once statement. You would need to add another path if you wanted a different directory to be searched in addition to these two. That is identified in the php.ini or php.conf file on your system via the include_path option in that file.

Comment: So i can put my include files either of the locations and goving it owners permissions and it will work

Comment: You can put the php files in the include or pear directory and php will find them when it needs to include them in another file via the include or require_once directive. php will need read/execute permissions on those files to be able to read them and to execute them. That means that the id under which php is operating will need to have those permissions assigned to them for that directory and files. It should already have those permissions as part of the installation process. You can determine who that is via the get_current_user() php function.

Comment: i added the connection file in /usr/share/pear and /usr/share/php folder with owner accessible with which domain name is working.But still the file is not picked up.i m including like this- include 'connection.php'.please correct me as i m nt able to correct it

Comment: stackman, just ran a couple of tests. if php cannot find the file, it should generate an error at the include statement and notify you of the error and also post the same to the php_error.log. If that is the situation, then you should see a php error like the following, where I intentionally attempted to load "getAccess.php" knowing it was not in my PEAR directory: include(getAccess.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/--name--/Sites/slnseeker/protected/test.php on line 5. I prefer the require_once directive: require_once "getAccess.php"; (note semicolon at end)

Comment: K.i will test that sir and will come back to u.thanks

Comment: i tested it sir.it said failed to open file.permission denied.Although the owner for included file and get_current_user() returned user both are same.tht file is having owner access only which means get_current_user()  is the owner.its looking in root html directory for that path

Comment: when you say that php is looking in the root html directory for the include path, do you mean that it is looking where you expect it to look? for example, if www == your root html directory and your include file is in '/usr/share/pear/' is php now looking in www/usr/share/pear for your includes and is that the correct path? Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: Doing a little research on StackOverflow, see if the following answers your question now: [how-to-set-root-folder-for-php-include-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882915/how-to-set-root-folder-for-php-include-files)

Comment: www is my root html directory where my all files are placed and where i want the server to search for file.i m running in linux aws server

Comment: forgive me if I seem a little confused. part of what you've written indicates that php cannot find the file. that would be logical if your base directory on your aws server does not have a usr/share directory structure, which is what you've indicated is specified in your include_path option in your php config file. Some of your comments indicate that php CAN find the file, but doesn't have the correct permissions. I'm confused. What's the specific error in your php error log?

Comment: Hi sir.the problem was solved.it was some different user which we need to check with other command rather than get current user

Comment: StackMan, That's great to read that you solved the problem. Congrats!

Comment: thanks a lot fr ur valueable guidance which has increased my knowledge owards this module of linux