# how to specify file paths in webpage so the same file works on server and localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to develop a website locally to eventually FTP to my server. My `index.php` file includes the following line:

```
 <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/header.php");?>
```

The idea is to include a separate `header.php` file in every page on the website. This code works on the server, but not in localhost because the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .` part is only valid for the server.

Is there a way to get the path correct for BOTH server and localhost, so I don't need to edit every webpage when moving from localhost to server?

The above relates to PHP, but I'll also need to answer the same question for HTML code, for example:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="site name" />
```

begins at the web root on the server. Is this going to work on localhost?

I'm assuming this must be a common need, and wonder what the conventional wisdom is. I'm not using a framework (just a text editor). Thanks in advance for any comments/help.

UPDATE

I see a similar question here,

[How to set root folder for PHP include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882915/how-to-set-root-folder-for-php-include-files)

although the answers relate to using a config.php file, which I don't have, and don't address the HTML portion.

Comment: How could `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` only be valid on one server and not the other?

Comment: By other server, I take it you mean localhost. It just points to a different location (e.g. the root is different, thus the same code can't be used for both localhost and server).

Comment: Are the domain's files stored in a subdirectory of the web root on your local server but not on the production server? Or vice versa?

Comment: No, looks like the DOCUMENT_ROOT on localhost (Mac Mavericks) points to `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and my files are stored in `/Users/myname/Sites/` folder.

Comment: That makes no sense. How can the files not be within the DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: By default a main php file is used with basic settings. What is the problem to define one variable based on your enviroment to be use in your whole application?

Comment: @Steffomio, probably nothing, but I'm a PHP newbie. By `main php file` are you referring to a `config.php` file? Is that how it's typically done? How to address the HTML portion?

Comment: Given your statements about localhost vs. web server I _have_ to ask... are you actually _serving_ your files via the localhost web server or are you just _opening_ them from `/Users/myname/Sites/` ... or are you serving them as `~myname/application/somefile.php` on localhost vs `/application/somefile.php` on the "real" server?

Comment: @stephenP, Wow, that's confusing. I followed this link's instructions to setup and verify Apache and PHP working: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083 , then I edit my php files in VI editor, then I enter in a browser, `http://localhost/~myname/index.php`. Is that what I should be doing?

Comment: main php file: Simply create a File with your settings named like "app-config.php" in the same folder where your index.php is located. Next add in your index.php File in the very first lines "require_once('app-config.php');" and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go back in your file hierarchy using `../` as much times as you have folders.

```
<?php include "../../includes/header.php";?>
```

same in html

```
<img src="../../images/logo.png" alt="site name" />
```

If your file structure is big, try using a base like this in a separate file for your localhost and server:

localhost:`<?php $base= 'http://localhost';?>`

and server:`<?php $base= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>`

and then in all your pages you can do `include("../../base.php");`

this way you only have to type `../`once in every page

Comment: I see what you're saying. But, for large directory structures, is there a way to use an absolute path?

Comment: I dont think so, you might want to wait for others to come up with solutions but I've never heard of a better way. sorry

Comment: Thanks @SamApostel, that very well could be the best approach. Not sure, but it's really simple and intuitive. Thanks

Comment: wait, I might have found a better approach

Comment: I'm not following the 2nd approach here. Can you explain it more? There's a separate `base.php` file with different definitions of `$base` for localhost and server. I include that file in each webpage php file, so the variable $base can be used in each webpage. I need to update the `../../` once on each page, where the include occurs. Thereafter on the webpage, when I want to use an absolute path, I just insert `<?php $base . ?>`. For example, `<?php include($base . "/includes/header.php");?>`, or `<img src="<?php $base . ?>/images/logo.png" alt="site name" />`. Is that right?

Comment: Getting an issue on localhost: `Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`. Seems allowing to include as a URL is a security risk and should be avoided in favor of using a local file path. Since it's only for my local machine, should be OK though. Wouldn't want it on the server though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113684/discussion-between-sam-apostel-and-user46688).

Comment: Accepting as answer because the original solution posted here for simply adding `../../` is great. If someone is looking for a way to get absolute paths for both PHP and HTML that can be used both on localhost as well as remote server, then the accepted solution to the link provided in the update of the original question above can be used (I also got it working). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use an approach like Sam's as it's simple and portable but it can fall apart on larger and more complex applications. For these situations you can define your paths in a config file. You'll still have to know the relative path to that file from your script, but after that everything will be easy.

```
//config.php
define("DOCPATH","c:/dev");
define("ROOTURL","http://localhost/");

//your file
include_once("../../config.php");
set_include_path(DOCPATH);
```

You can then use php in your image src

```
<img src="<?php echo ROOTURL;?>images/logo.png" alt="site name" />
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are there two config files, one for server and another for localhost? When to use DOCPATH vs ROOTURL?

Comment: Just one file. Change the values when you upload to the server. It would be nice to automate these values but sometimes hard-coding is just safer.

Comment: I like to setup something in my application so on initialization I set application level variables based on environment variables. It can be as something as simple as setting the application variable based on the URL as the URL would define the environment.

Comment: When to use DOCPATH vs ROOTURL? Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: `DOCPATH` is for accessing filesystem files with PHP. `ROOTURL` is for use in your HTML references.