# how to set a global link in php

Tags: php, include

I have a question, I have a file in php where I need to include another one

```
<?php include('includefile.php'); ?>
```

but if I am in a subfolder I have to call this file like this

```
<?php include('../includefile.php'); ?>
```

however, some lines in this files will change, example

```
<a href="css/style.css">
```

now is

```
<a href="../css/style.css">
```

How can I do to set no matter where in the project

thanks

Comment: Use an absolute path based on the root of your project directory. Then you won't need to mess around with `../`.

Comment: can you explain me better please

Comment: Sure, please see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set root folder for PHP include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882915/how-to-set-root-folder-for-php-include-files)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, how this is achieved is by using a define which is named something like `ROOT` which stores the absolute path to the root of your project:

**config.php**

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Then in your other files, you include this one file (config.php) and make use of the `ROOT` define in your code. This saves you the hassle of having to worry about the `../` and how many directories up you need to go etc.

**Reading Material**

[Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: I dont understand yet, can u give me a example with the links that I wrote? please

Comment: @kevinyepez I'm not sure how else to simplify my explanation also, I have no intention to write your code for you when I've given an explanation.